# Need help posting first python program on github

Tags: python, github

I have finally created my own program that works. I am trying to upload the code to github for my first portfolio submission. I added github desktop to my macbook to try to make it easy to upload the code, but I can't figure it out. All of my code ending in .py is unable to be added to github. Can anyone offer advice on what I need to do to get this up?

Below is the latest screenshot from the error I am receiving:

[image]

Comment: What actually happens when you try this?  Does the commit succeed but the code does not appear?  Did you remember to push?

Comment: I've watched numerous videos on youtube and I still can't figure it out. I believe git has been added to my terminal, but nothing seems to work. I'm completely confused.

Comment: It will not let me even push the code onto the github desktop application I downloaded. Is there a way to just copy and paste the code?

Comment: @M.Sacchetti It might not be the best idea (as learning git basics will probably be really helpful if you deal frequently with source code and/or want to contribute to some projects), but actually if you are in a hurry you can use the web interface to upload your files on github.com. Simply drag and drop your file(s) on the page of your repository on github.com and you will see a message like "drop to upload files".

Comment: If it won't let you do it, what is the error message, if any?

Comment: It doesn't give me an error message. It will not allow me to click on the program I made and push it onto github. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your `.gitignore` file?

Or just try to push it with the command line interface (to learn the basics of the `git` commands, see [gitcsm site](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository), or follow github [instruction](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/) after you create your repo

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repo-name.git
```

As a last step, you need to push your "master" branch to "origin" remote and set up tracking

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: I tried adding your first line of "git init" but I received an error message in my terminal.

Comment: How do I share the .gitignore file?

Comment: If you got an error on git init, please post what the error message said.  Note that git init only makes changes to your local folders and does not interact with the github site.   Make sure you are running git init from the folder containing your project, and that the folder is writable.

Comment: It's not giving me an error message. It will not allow me to click on my program in the github desktop. The program is not highlighted and I can't figure out a way to push it into the github desktop application. I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: Please read [this site](http://superuser.com/questions/991778/git-add-ignored-files-from-within-github-desktop), you'll find your `.gitignore`, file. if you get again error message, please screenshot and upload or copy the text to your main post.

Comment: Maybe [this tutorial](https://dannguyen.github.io/github-for-portfolios/lessons/clone-github-pages-repo/) will helping you, note: this is not my site.

Comment: Thank you for that. I added the program like you stated and went in again to add it as a new repository, but it ignored again.

Comment: How do I add a screen shot on this comment section?

Comment: What if you just edit your main post. So everyone can see look your trouble, any maybe you will have more help. To add image you have to use mini-Markdown formatting

Comment: I was able to add a screen shot to my original post above so you can see the issue I am running into. The program I am trying to add to github is "firstprogramgame.py", which is in the folder that is on the screen shot. For some reason it will not let me select it and add it to github.

Comment: Sorry I can't see error on your image, but I hope you want to try this. For this case you just need to pust 1 file, so try this command `git add firstprogramgame.py` then commit and push with command like on top

Comment: I tried the "git add firstprogramgame.py" in the terminal and I received an error message. I am posting a screenshot of the error message in my main post above. Let me know what you think I should do. I didn't think uploading code to github would be this difficult. I look forward to your response.

Comment: ok lets see, run this command `xcode-select --install`, then retry git add

Comment: when I typed in "Xcode-select --install" it tried to install some tools. Is that correct?

Comment: Ok. I have downloaded all of the tools and then typed in what you stated above. I received a message that I am posting in the body of my original question again. I still don't see the code uploaded on github. I'm not sure what to look for at this point.

Comment: Try to remove `.gitignore` file first, before you enter git add

Comment: I have uploaded a screen shot of typing in the ignored file in the command line. It is above like the others. I can't believe how difficult github is. It's been almost 3 days and still can't upload my code.

Comment: Relax plas, I hope you would to searching on search engine before you ask basic syntax. make sure your in same diretory with your file `.gitignore` then `rm .gitignore`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking me to do with .gitignore and rm.gitignore I'm not sure how to navigate with what you are asking. I'm completely lost now.

Comment: I tried something else and it was unable to push the code to github. I have attached a screenshot of how it looks in the terminal. Let me know if you have any further suggestions.  Thanks.

Comment: I suggest you to create new folder then copy your `firstprogramgame.py` into it, and try every sintax from beginning, from `git init` - `git push`

Comment: I believe I have finally been able to upload the code. I deleted everything I had created before and started a new repository. I created a new branch and uploaded the code. Here it is: https://github.com/celticslegends/First-Program.git

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help me.